# Wordpress plugin boilerplate AJAX functionality

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I am using the WP-STRAP Wordpress plugin boilerplate https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate .

I want to send data from frontend via a form to backend with JS Fetch API. Upon request a custom post is created and populated with data from frontend like post title and so on.

Issue: I get 400/500 response error if i place my php action/functions in a class.

According to the Github page, all public-facing hooks/functionality should be placed in src -> App -> Frontend folder. I tried but it doesn't work. For example i created a file/class FrontEndRequests.php and i placed my actions/functions there, but with no luck - action isn't working upon ajax request.

So my guess is that the action/function are called via the wrong hook or due to the boilerplate structure they are called at the wrong time (too late or too soon).

I made it "work" by having the following structure but i want to do it the right way :

1. In the main plugin file `the-plugin-name.php` in the root folder i added my action hooks and function :

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_ajax_actions');


function my_ajax_actions() {
    add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_post", 'insert_post');
    add_action("wp_ajax_insert_post", 'insert_post');
}

/**
 * Insert post with data from frontend
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function insert_post() {

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'fetch_fr_ajax_nonce' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nonce' );
    }

    echo "inserting Post" . "\n";

    $page_slug = 'custom-post'; // Slug of the Post
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type'     => PostTypes::POST_TYPE['id'],              // Post Type Slug eg: 'page', 'post'
        'post_title'    => $_POST['title'], // Title of the Content
        'post_content'  => 'Test Page Content', // Content
        'post_status'   => 'pending',           // Post Status
        'post_name'     => $page_slug       // Slug of the Post
    );

    if (!get_page_by_path( $page_slug, OBJECT, 'page')) { // Check If Page Doesn't Exits
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
    }

    echo "Post Inserted successfully" . "\n";

        wp_die();
    }
```

2. Script localization in `Frontend folder -> Enqueue.php` file :

```
        global $wp_query;

        // localize script and send variables
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-frontend', 'fetch_fr_ajax',
            [
                'ajax_url'  => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'wp_query_vars' => $wp_query->query_vars,
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'fetch_fr_ajax_nonce' ),
            ]
        );
```

3. In `assets -> src -> js` i have the JS Fetch file :

```
'use strict'

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    const sendCTA = document.querySelector('.insert-post-btn');

    const data = new FormData()

    data.append('action', 'insert_post')
    data.append( 'nonce', fetch_fr_ajax.nonce);
    data.append('title', 'Post from frontend');

    const params = new URLSearchParams(data)

    if (sendCTA) {
        sendCTA.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('.post-btn clicked')

            fetch(fetch_fr_ajax.ajax_url, {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                body: params,
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.text();
                }
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data); // handle the response from the server
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error); // handle any errors that occur
            });
        })
    }
})
```

For demo purposes i added a button in `templates -> test-template.php` and upon click via Fetch Api the respective action is called and the post is inserted into Wordpress Custom Post Type.

How can i structure it in the OOP way that the boilerplate is made ?

Yes, i could ask this here https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate but it seems that project has been abandoned, as nobody replies there. Please help !

Comment: "I get 400/500 response error" - there should be more detail in the server error log, the WordPress debug log or the PHP error log if separate. Please can you find those?

Comment: But it shouldn't matter where the code goes as long as it's included/required and the namespaces work OK.

Comment: @Rup usually i received 400 for the case when logged-in and 500 for the case when i wasn't logged (for example incognito). 

If it doesn't matter where the action/function are placed then why this code works well if placed in `functions.php`  of any theme and the root plugin boilerplate file `the-plugin-name.php ` of this boilerplate . I still think that the boilerplate structure and the order of how things are called matter in this case. 

Maybe other classes are called too late ?

Comment: Huh. I could believe there were namespace issues but it looks like it can find my_ajax_actions by name but not insert_post just below it, so there mustn't be. Not sure.

Comment: Oh you've deleted the error message now? It might be useful to edit that into the question. You don't need the stack trace as it's just the calling-a-hook stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "resolved" it in the following way:

In `src -> App -> Frontend -> FrontRequestHandler.php` i added the handler function that will insert the Custom Post.

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Enqueue
 *
 * @package DemoPlugin\App\Frontend
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
class FrontRequestHandler extends Base {

    /**
     * Initialize the class.
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function init() {
        /**
         * This frontend class is only being instantiated in the frontend as requested in the Bootstrap class
         *
         * @see Requester::isFrontend()
         * @see Bootstrap::__construct
         *
         * Add plugin code here
         */
    }

    /**
     * Insert post with data from frontend
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function insert_post() {

    // Prevent processing requests from external sources
    check_ajax_referer( 'fetch_fr_ajax_nonce', 'nonce' );

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'fetch_fr_ajax_nonce' ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nonce' );
    }

    echo "inserting Demo Plugin Post" . "\n";

    $page_slug = 'custom-post'; // Slug of the Post
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type'     => PostTypes::POST_TYPE['id'],              // Post Type Slug eg: 'page', 'post'
        'post_title'    => sanitize_text_field($_POST['title']),    // Title of the Content
        'post_content'  => 'Test Page Content', // Content
        'post_status'   => 'pending',           // Post Status
        'post_name'     => $page_slug       // Slug of the Post
    );

    if (!get_page_by_path( $page_slug, OBJECT, 'page')) { // Check If Page Doesn't Exits
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
    }

    echo "Demo Plugin Post Inserted successfully" . "\n";

    wp_die();
    }
    
}
```

In `src -> App -> General -> PostTypes.php` :

In the init function i added the action called on `wp_loaded` hook (other hooks proved to not work the same).

```
public function init() {
        /**
         * This general class is always being instantiated as requested in the Bootstrap class
         *
         * @see Bootstrap::__construct
         *
         * Add plugin code here
         */
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', [$this, 'frontAjaxRequest'] );
    }
```

Then below in the same PostTypes.php file i would have the callback function which contains the ajax action hooks (wp_ajax_nopriv & wp_ajax for both logged and non logged users) :

```
/**
     * Add actions for the frontend ajax request
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function frontAjaxRequest() {
        $frontRequestHandler = new FrontRequestHandler();

        add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_insert_post", [ $frontRequestHandler, 'insert_post']);
        add_action("wp_ajax_insert_post", [ $frontRequestHandler, 'insert_post']);  
    }
```

The game changer seems to be the hook `wp_loaded` - now the ajax handler works for all users. Also placing the `frontAjaxRequest`  in the init() function of the PostTypes.php also had some impact. I tried placing this function in other Classes/Files and it didn't work.  The previous  `init` hook was working only for the non-logged users.

I am not sure this is the best way to do it, but it works, the code logic is separated.

Comment: @Rup What are your thoughts on this ? Again, i am not sure this is the best way to do it...